# Cannot use material-ui with storybook "Can't resolve '@emotion/react'"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

I am using `webpack@5` for storybook of my project. The problem is when I use my component in storybook (which uses `material-ui` components) I get error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in '/Users/USER/Dev/PROJECT/front/packages/components/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/GlobalStyles'`

I have tried to install this package, add it to `addons`, add alias for this module to storybook config, install other strange `material-ui` modules. Nothing works for me, still the same error.

Can you help and suggest what I can try to solve this?

Comment: did you follow the official documentation of the storybook to use material-UI?

https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-material-ui

Comment: yes, but it looks like it is mostly done for previous `storybook` versions, and provided solution for `storybook@6` simply does not work, what more, I do not need theme customization, my problem is strictly for building the storybook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found some solution on a page and it works for me:

```js
//main.js
webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return merge(config, {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@emotion/react': getPackageDir('@emotion/react'),
        },
      },
    });
  },
```

```js
//main.js
function getPackageDir(filepath) {
  let currDir = path.dirname(require.resolve(filepath));
  while (true) {
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(currDir, 'package.json'))) {
      return currDir;
    }
    const { dir, root } = path.parse(currDir);
    if (dir === root) {
      throw new Error(`Could not find package.json in the parent directories starting from ${filepath}.`);
    }
    currDir = dir;
  }
}
```